# Bind a string value to a checkbox toggle using angular two-way data binding angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

```
<div class="form-group col-12 col-md-6">
     <label class="mb-1 mr-2">
         Status 
     </label> 
     <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox-toggle">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="status"
              [(ngModel)]="question.conditions[0].status">
                                    
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="status"></label>
      </div>  
 </div>
`
Conditions: [
  {
    "status": "",
    "questionId": {
      "eq": "6012e7378d65710016832916"
    },
    "selects": {
      "in": [
        "6012e7eb8d65710016832b61",
        "6012e7eb8d65710016832b65"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I want to binding my data is 'active' || 'disabled' to this toggle when i switching it.But it not works and crashing the page.My required is binding it with string value(not binding boolean value).

Comment: Please, post your .ts. And the message that appears in console when your screen crashes. For the readers to have more information about your problem : )

Answer (score 1):

Add `[checked]` attribute as below code, so that it will bind the property.

```
   <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="status" 
        [checked]="question.Conditions[0].status != '' || question.Conditions[0].status != 'true' ?  true: false "
            [(ngModel)]="question.Conditions[0].status">
```

There is something which is missed from json, *Conditions* to *conditions* (if not typo)

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: can i ask? where can i add my string value which is 'active' or 'disabled' inside your suggestion?Can you detail

Answer (score 1):

Try using **(change)** and bind your value there

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="status"
            [(ngModel)]="question.Conditions[0].status"  
(change)="question.Conditions[0].status = question.Conditions[0].status ? 'active' : 'disable';">
```

You can assign the value on changing of the checkbox

Comment: use simply `<input ... [ngModel]="question.Conditions[0].status=='active'" (ngModelChange)="question.Conditions[0].status=$event?'active':'disabled'">`